# Does Crate.io support nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, document, crate

I couldn't find the answer in their documentation.

I know they support complex objects, but i want to know if they support nested documents that are mapped with the nested document schema as in elasticsearch,
which should allow querying capabilities of nested properties in the context of the same nested document.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are referring to this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html ?

In CrateDB you'd have to do this manually by using a `JOIN` (it's SQL after all):

`SELECT p.title FROM posts p INNER JOIN comments c ON p.id = c.post_id WHERE c.name = 'Alice' AND c.age = 28`